# Can't delete pages from the Umbraco content

Tags: umbraco, package

I used the Webmatrix to setup an Umbraco website. Later on I integrated all the files in a Visual Studio 2010 project, developed and tested the whole website local.

I went live with the website and made sure that the webhosting provider (OpenHost) gives all the permissions suggested on our.umbraco.

The GoLive check inside the CMS was successful!

**Issues:**

- Unfortunately I can't delete pages from the content area. (Error handling action)
- Also the package folder in the Developers section is empty.

OpenHost can't help anymore and are not able to change permission of the windows temp folder, as suggested in some forums.

Comment: Hi, If you are getting errors it would help if you could post the actual errors (including stack trace) that you receive. Also any entries in the umbracolog table in the database that relate to these errors.

Comment: As well which version of Umbraco you are using, and have you set up MediumTrust settings in web.config file?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for a similar problem this way. I discovered the problem when I tried to delete a macro, but after further investigation nothing in the backoffice would delete including content.

The HTTP response contained a generic 500 Server Error so I ran a trace on the failed request (instructions on how to setup failed request tracing are [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis/)) The trace pointed to an error in the LiveStreamingHandler module, some kind of invalid index. Googling this error gave me a list of results that discussed the invalid index error in IIS Media Service 4.1. I uninstalled media services completely and delete in Umbraco worked. I don't have a need for media services now, but I tried reinstalling IIS Media Services 4.0 and everything still seems fine.

I wasn't able to determine exactly why Media Services 4.1 is failing, but this might be something to check for in solving this problem.

The original thread on our.umbraco.com is found [here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/umbraco-5-general-discussion/30167-500-Server-Error-when-deleting-a-macro).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you were missing some assemblies in the bin folder that were referenced by your packages. I'm guessing that when you transferred the project from your dev environment, some files were missed in the process.